# Spring MVC Google Search Console verification

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Very simple problem, but i can't see the clear solution.

I use Spring MVC.
need to serve a static single page like:

http://example.com/googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html

Faced a hundred probs with that already. Don't want to build any complicated workarounds. IT is just a one simple single page :(

**How to do it, most simple way?**

Answer (score 1):

From this Getting Started guide: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

You would want to put your html page into `src/main/resources/static`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it would be helpful to let us know what problems you are facing exactly, my guess is that it has to do with the needed setup of a `Controller` to receive the `@RequestMapping`. On situations like yours where you want to directly forward a url to the view bypassing the Controller you need to setup a [view-controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller).

Assuming that in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` configuration you already have setup your `ViewResolver`:

```
<!-- here assuming jsp for view -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

you'll need in the same file (if you don't have already):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

and finally the definition of your page:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html" view-name="my_page_name"/>
```

Comment: thanks. what is the path to view-name should looks like?

Comment: it's the path after your domain name/ip address. You'd normally put that on the Controller's @RequestMapping. In my answer I gave an example of how it would look given your provided url

Comment: the request must be done exactly to that path.
so, is it
<mvc:view-controller path="/googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html" view-name="googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html"/>  ??

Comment: if i do     `<mvc:view-controller path="/static/googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html" view-name="googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html"/>`, put my page source to `/static/googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html` and make a request to `googlef80f3557at5t5y2c5.html` - got 404.